# How can I set RequestedAuthenticationContext in spring-security for ADFS?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I tested it with [this](https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/ClaimsXray/TokenRequest) tool and I found that I need Authentication type: **Form** and Token request: **SAML-P (SAML2.0)** but I don't know how can I configure the spring-security to send RequestedAuthenticationContext as **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport** instead of **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Kerberos** in the SAML request.

So instead of that:

- **Authentication type**: Windows Integrated Authentication
- **Token request:** SAML-P (SAML 2.0)
- **Request to IdP:** GET https://ospa.company.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn?
  LoginToRP=urn:microsoft:adfs:claimsxray&
  RequestedAuthenticationContext=**urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Kerberos**
- **Response from IdP:**

```xml
<samlp:Response ID="..."
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="..."
                Destination="https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/ClaimsXray/TokenResponse"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    ...
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="..." SessionIndex="...">
            <AuthnContext>

     <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Kerberos</AuthnContextClassRef>

            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I need this:

- **Authentication type**: Forms
- **Token request:** SAML-P (SAML 2.0)
- **Request to IdP:** GET https://ospa.company.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn?
  LoginToRP=urn:microsoft:adfs:claimsxray&
  RequestedAuthenticationContext=**urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport**
- **Response from IdP:**

```xml
<samlp:Response ID="..."
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="..."
                Destination="https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/ClaimsXray/TokenResponse"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    ...
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="..." SessionIndex="...">
            <AuthnContext>

     <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>

            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

**UPDATE:**
We use spring-boot 2.5.5

Comment: Are you using the latest Spring Security, which ships with SAML support? (There is a deprecated `spring-security-saml` plugin, too, which is why I ask.) Also, am I understanding correctly that you are an SP that wants Spring Security to redirect to the endpoint you described to initiate authentication?

Comment: We have a common spring boot lib, which uses the 2.2.5.RELEASE version of spring boot. I can upgrade the patch version only if it is necessary. The spring-security-saml2-service-provider's version is 5.2.2.RELEASE. We don't use the saml plugin.

Comment: The case you described is exactly what we want to achieve.

Comment: If it can't be solved that way, I can skip the common lib and use the latest spring security in the main application.

Comment: Of course, it would be best if I could solve this somehow in the common lib.

Comment: In the meantime, we decided to upgrade the spring boot version of the common lib to the latest version. My question is the same, but how can I achieve this in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. An `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is how you tell Spring Security where to redirect when authentication is needed.

Since you simply need to redirect when authentication is needed, you can use the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` like so:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://ospa.company.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn? LoginToRP=urn:microsoft:adfs:claimsxray& RequestedAuthenticationContext=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport";

    AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = 
            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(url);

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .saml2Login(withDefaults())
        .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
        );
    
    return http.build();
}
```

Please also ensure that you [configure your application with your IdP's corresponding metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/saml2/index.html#_specifying_identity_provider_metadata).

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me:

```java
@Configuration
public class SamlConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(registrations);
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver(registrationResolver);
        authenticationRequestResolver.setAuthnRequestCustomizer((context) -> context.getAuthnRequest().setRequestedAuthnContext(buildRequestedAuthnContext()));
        return authenticationRequestResolver;
    }

    private RequestedAuthnContext buildRequestedAuthnContext() {
        // Create AuthnContextClassRef
        AuthnContextClassRefBuilder authnContextClassRefBuilder = new AuthnContextClassRefBuilder();
        AuthnContextClassRef authnContextClassRef = authnContextClassRefBuilder.buildObject(SAMLConstants.SAML20_NS, AuthnContextClassRef.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_LOCAL_NAME, SAMLConstants.SAML20_PREFIX);
        authnContextClassRef.setURI(AuthnContext.PPT_AUTHN_CTX);

        // Create RequestedAuthnContext
        RequestedAuthnContextBuilder requestedAuthnContextBuilder = new RequestedAuthnContextBuilder();
        RequestedAuthnContext requestedAuthnContext = requestedAuthnContextBuilder.buildObject();
        requestedAuthnContext.setComparison(AuthnContextComparisonTypeEnumeration.EXACT);
        requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(authnContextClassRef);

        return requestedAuthnContext;
    }
}
```

It produces the following SAML Request:

```xml
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     AssertionConsumerServiceURL="..."
                     Destination="..."
                     ForceAuthn="false"
                     ID="..."
                     IsPassive="false"
                     IssueInstant="..."
                     ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                     Version="2.0"
                     >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Tested with Spring Boot 2.7.17, including OpenSAML 4.0.1.